# Unable to draw a simple image using JComponent

Tags: image, swing, java, imageicon

I'm using netbeans IDE to practice some Java basic code. But I'm unsuccessful to draw a PNG image. Below is my code,

```
package JavaApplication1;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MyCanvas extends JComponent
{
    Image img;
    public MyCanvas(){
        img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("pengbrew.png");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    }
}

public class JavaGame
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Image demo");
        window.getContentPane().add( new MyCanvas() );
        window.setSize(400,400);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

I added the images in the netbeans project.

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Comment: Could be due to the location where you've saved the PNG image.

Comment: Raze likely summarizes your problem. Where are you images in relation to your class files? Where are they in relation to your user directory (where Java is currently looking to find the images)?

Answer (score 2):

easiest ways is look for [JLabel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) that's best of [JComponents](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) for [Icon/ImageIcon](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html) examples [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/Label.htm)

Answer (score 2):

To load an image use `ImageIO.read(File file)`.  It's a newer API, easier to use and better supported.  A tutorial on loading images is here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html if you need some more pointers.

Your code would look like this instead,

```
Image img;
public MyCanvas(){
    try {
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("pengbrew.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Handle exception if there is one.
    }
}
```

For the long answer about why the method you were using wasn't working is probably because of the following...

Your image may be in the proper location and instead Toolkit.createImage() hasn't finished loading the image before the frame comes up to paint.  Toolkit.createImage() returns control back to your application before the underlying image has actually finished being loaded.  You can usually verify if this is the issue by resizing your application to force it to repaint.  If after a few seconds of trying to resize the application the image shows up it was due to the image not being loaded during the first paint calls.

To ensure that the image is loaded before you continue you need to use a MediaTracker.  Here is some example code to ensure loading of Image is complete before using it.

```
Component component = new Component() {};
MediaTracker TRACKER = new MediaTracker(component);

...

Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("imageToLoad.png");
synchronized(TRACKER) {
   int id = ++mediaTrackerID;
   TRACKER.addImage(image, id);
   try {
       TRACKER.waitForID(id, 0);
   } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
       image = null;
   }
   TRACKER.removeImage(image, id);
}
// Now you can use your image.
```

You'll see code just like this in the ImageIcon class in the method loadImage(Image image).

Comment: Also consider `ImageIO.read()`, mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7045214/230513).

Comment: Remember that there is a performance difference between the two methods.  ImageIO is slower than using the MediaTracker but ImageIO is the newer API, does a LOT more and better to use.  I just wish that Oracle would improve the performance of it.

Comment: IIUC, `ImageIO` has a fixed latency; is it also slower?

Comment: @trashgod I've written a simple test to load a jpeg from a file and print out the times used to load using media tracker and ImageIO.  The media tracker method is at least 2x faster when I load a 129k jpg.  I had done this with smaller files years ago but don't have the numbers.  More than happy to post my perf test case somewhere if you're interested.

Comment: No need, but consider updating your answer; +1 from earlier, btw.

Comment: Done.  I left the original answer for completeness but put the ImageIO implementation first.  If you think I should remove the media tracker portion please tell me.  Thanks again for your help!