# Netbeans matisse, custom button icon property error

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, matisse

I have created a custom `JButton` where override the `setIcon`.

```
public class TestButton extends JButton {

    public TestButton() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void setIcon(Icon icon) {
        super.setIcon(icon);
        imgToBufferedImg(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("test.png"));
    }
}
```

And here is the *imgToBufferedImg* method.

```
public BufferedImage imgToBufferedImg(Image image) {
    if (image == null) {
        return null;
    }
    if (image instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return ((BufferedImage) image);
    } else {
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(
                image.getWidth(null),
                image.getHeight(null),
                BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        Graphics g = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
        g.dispose();

        return bufferedImage;
    }
}
```

I have added this component in Matisse, no problem, however, when i try to set the icon property of the button i get the error:

> Failed to write the value to the property "icon"

The problem seems to come from the *imgToBufferedImg* since i can set the property if i remove the call to this method in `setIcon`. What is wrong with my image conversion method?

EDIT:

The following test succeeded:

```
try {
    imgToBufferedImg(ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("test.png")));
} catch (IOException ex) {
    Exceptions.printStackTrace(ex);
}
```

Also i just figured out that the problem is caused by:

```
((ImageIcon) icon).getImage();
```

Running this code when the UI is ready (e.g using a `SwingUtilities.invokeLater`) seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem might be in `Toolkit#createImage()`. `ImageIO.read()` might be better. Also, it looks like you're throwing away the result from `imgToBufferedImg()`.

Comment: It does not look like, i'm throwing away the result. I tried a make this test case as simple as possible to show that the only fact to call my method raise the problem. In my actual project, i do thinks differently of course, the code you can see in my question is the result of a code refactoring a target the problem. I don't think the problem comes from Toolkit since it's supposed to return an Image from a path as String.

Comment: @nathan: `Toolkit` "operations may be performed asynchronously." Your `Image` may be incomplete when you try to render it. `ImageIO.read()` is worth a try.

Answer (score 2):

no reason why

- create `BufferedImage` inside `JButtons setIcon()`, there you would be to set (for `JButton`) `Icon`, `ImageIcon`
- this `BufferedImage` (should be `Icon`, `ImageIcon`) is create after is added to `JButton`

---

but

- method could be `BufferedImage to Icon, ImageIcon`
- whats wrong with `JButton#setIcon()`
- [you can use paintComponent() too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7115766/714968)

Comment: not sure to understand. Actually the code i show was a test case and i need to load images regarding the icon set. So i need to call this code each time a new icon is set. Actually, i fill an array of ImageIcon containing post-effected icons.

Comment: `post-effected icons` in `JButtons API` are impelemented a fwe methods for `setXxxIcon` directly, or to use [ButtonModel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton/5755124#5755124) , maybe there any reason to override `JButton` ...

Comment: :-) matisse call one method. setIcon. i'd like to call my logic from this method. I'm aware of those methods and i use them but after executing the logic within setIcon. My question is why my method imgToBufferedImg cause the mentioned error.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the thrashed comment:

*Toolkit "operations may be performed asynchronously." Your Image may be incomplete when you try to render it.*

I was able to figure out what the problem was. Straight from the `setIcon` method, i requested the image from the icon:

```
((ImageIcon) icon).getImage()
```

But this image is definitively incomplete. Putin my logic within the event dispatching thread did the trick.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        //requesting icon images here
    }
}
```

Comment: Always a good idea. There's more ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7045214/261156).