# LayerUI, g.drawImage underlined

Tags: java, image, swing, java-7, jlayer

```
public class GraphicsBoard extends LayerUI {
    String picPath = "pictures/";
    String[] fileName = { "cards.png", "BlackJackBoard.png" };
    ClassLoader cl = GraphicsBoard.class.getClassLoader();
    URL imgURL[] = new URL[2];
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    Image imgCards, imgBG;

    public GraphicsBoard() throws Exception {
        for (int x = 0; x < 2; x++)
            imgURL[x] = cl.getResource(picPath + fileName[x]);
        imgCards = tk.createImage(imgURL[0]);
        imgBG = tk.createImage(imgURL[1]);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(imgBG, 0, 0, 550, 450, 0, 0, 551, 412, this);
    }
}
```

So thats my code for the underpart of a blackjac game im making. However, in eclipse drawImage in the paintComponent is underlined and I'm not really sure how to fix it. when i hover over it, it says

```
The method drawImage(Image, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, ImageObserver) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Image, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, GraphicsBoard)
```

and the option given to me are

```
Cast argument 'this' to 'ImageObserver'
```

and

```
Let 'GraphicsBoard' implement 'ImageObserver'
```

If I run it, the layer on top (which is basically a JPanel with a  button) is not transparent.

This is what i use to add the JLayer to my Frame

```
OverBoard overLay = new OverBoard();
GraphicsBoard graphicsBG = new GraphicsBoard();
add(new JLayer(overLay, graphicsBG));
```

Comment: @trashgod its not a import promblem, its not compiling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As trashgod said, use ImageIO.read() to read your image, and then you can set the ImageObserver parameter to null, and you don't need to implement ImageObserver.

> If I run it, the layer on top (which is basically a JPanel with a button) is not transparent.

That is the expected behavior. Notice how in the [JLayer tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html#drawing) they use the line

```
g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, .5f));
```

to achieve transparency.

Answer (score 3):

The final parameter to `drawImage()` must implement the `ImageObserver` interface. If `LayerUI` does so, you can specify `this`. Alternatively, consider using `ImageIO.read()` to read images synchronously, and specify `null` as the final parameter.

Comment: See also [`Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage()` vs `ImageIO.read()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12041474/230513) and this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7045214/230513).

Comment: I know that, Im asking on how to fix that, I dont want to implement ImageObserver because i dont even know how to use it

Comment: What is `LayerUI`? What happens when you try `this` or `null`.

Comment: trashgod: LayerUI must be javax.swing.plaf.LayerUI (which appeared in Java 7)